# Sphinx + Postgres + uuid issues

Tags: postgresql, sphinx

I have a `sql_query` for a source defined like so:

```
 sql_query               = SELECT \
  criteria.item_uuid, \
  criteria.user_id, \
  criteria.color, \
  criteria.selection, \
  criteria.item_id, \
  home.state, \
  item.* \
  FROM criteria \
  INNER JOIN item USING (item_uuid) \
  INNER JOIN user_info home USING (user_id) \
  WHERE criteria.item_uuid IS NOT NULL
```

And then an index:

```
 index csearch {
  source                  = csearch
  path                    = /usr/local/sphinx/var/data/csearch
  docinfo                 = extern
  enable_star             = 1
  min_prefix_len          = 0
  min_infix_len           = 0
  morphology              = stem_en
 }
```

But when I run `indexer --rotate csearch` I get:

```
 indexing index 'csearch'...
 WARNING: zero/NULL document_id, skipping
```

The idea is that the `item_uuid` column is the identifier I want, based on some combination of the other columns. The `item_uuid` column is a uuid type in postgres: perhaps sphinx does not support this? Anyway, any ideas here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the docs, the document_id must be unique unsigned non-zero integers.

http://www.sphx.org/docs/manual-1.10.html#data-restrictions

You could try using SELECT row_number(), uuid, etc...

Comment: The manner in which you've responded to me has hurt my feelings and made me question my professional competency.